# python google geolocation api using wifi mac

Tags: python, json, google-maps, python-requests

I'm trying to use Google's API for geolocation giving wifi data to determine location.  This is their [intro](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro).  And this is my code

```
@author: Keith
"""

import requests

payload =         {
  "considerIp": "false",
  "wifiAccessPoints": [
    {
        "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ac",
        "signalStrength": -43,
        "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
    },
    {
        "macAddress": "00:25:9c:cf:1c:ad",
        "signalStrength": -55,
        "signalToNoiseRatio": 0
    }
  ],
  'key':'<MyAPIKey>'
}
r = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate', 
params=payload)
print(r.text)
```

This is the output

```
{
 "location": {
  "lat": 32.3643098,
  "lng": -88.703656
 },
 "accuracy": 6061.0
}
```

The request ignored all of the payload except the key portion and just found the geolocation using my IP address.  So I'm sending the json payload incorrectly.  I know this is probably really simple, but I'm stuck and couldn't find an example of python being used with requests to do this type of API query.  Thanks

Edit:
Picked up the cURL library and executed this command with success:

```
curl -d @your_filename.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=<myapikey>"
```

and got the output I expected.  I just want to be able to do the same thing in requests, but the data I'm trying to send is in "your_filename.json".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
r = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key='+ '<MyAPIKey>', json=payload)
```

Note the key was moved to query params (URL) and `json` argument was used in place of `params`.

Comment: Using json instead of data for param fixed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out the error of my ways.  Taking a better look at **requests.post** function, I see that I'm not using the parameters argument correctly.  After this, it worked perfectly,

```
r = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate', params=parameters, json=mydata, headers=headers)
```